# App Engine go111 Beta routing/handler wildcard ignores order?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go

I just tried the GO 1.11 App Engine Beta and the router/handler seems to be different. I use RESTful-VueJS approach and I used the following handler config:

```
- url: /v1/.*
  script: auto
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  secure: always

- url: /worker/.*
  script: auto
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/public/index.html
  upload: static/public/index.html
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  secure: always
```

In the first app engine generation the order of the handlers matters, the 1st one with a matching pattern wins. But this doesn't seem to work like this anymore. So even when I call a **"/v1/xyz"** I always receive the **"index.html"**

I guess that has to do with the fact that now in app engine all traffic is served using the entrypoint command. As far as I understand it tries to match `HandleFuncs()` that are set in main() or init()? And what if you use any web framework like me were you don't specify the routes in `main()` or `init()` because you want to use `mux`?